# Modification of custom Setting value -Web service error

Tags: apex, visualforce

My class uses a custom setting in a method that invokes a web service .
I added 6 new values to the custom setting and went back to the Case object to create a record .
And while saving , I am getting the error

"Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':HTML'."

Can the error be due the value addition ?
or just a connection issue?

Comment: We must see your code to assess. Please [edit] your post to include it.

Comment: Some web services return a HTML error message when a request fails rather than a valid SOAP XML response. Debug out the response and you may see an explanation of what the service doesn't like about your request.